# Dereferences a xml file from xcode

Tags: xcode

I made a huge mistaking in renaming my xml file from xcode and I'm not sure how to fix it. My app has a feature that reads all local xml files built with the project. So now it is reading 2 of the same xmls with different names.

I tried deleting the file, added it back in, and Dereferencing it but no luck. I also made sure to delete my app and re building the project. When I do a full system scan for the xml file nothing pops up. The xml file is currently in the Trash.

Another issue might have been with the svn remote server but I tried `svn rm --delete filename` and it said the file does not exist. ( I tried the project directory as well as a few other sub directories).

Is there a way to Dereference/delete the file from the project?